# Android: Switching content provider in runtime

Tags: android, sqlite, runtime, switch-statement, android-contentprovider

Hi 
My application implements 2 content providers:
1) Local - based on Sqlite
2) Remote - based on app engine.

When I am disconnected from the internet I want to use #1.
 When I have internet connectivity I would like to switch to #2.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Avishay

[30 min later... :-)
After a deeper research I think that by switching  the "content provider URI" I can switch from #1 to #2.

Avishay

Answer (score 1):

But the *right* answer is to use a `ContentProvider`, and use a `SyncAdapter` to keep the `ContentProvider`'s database constantly in sync with the App Engine database.  This will provide you fast local data access, and ensure that you're always running out of one consistent database.  Otherwise, you'll have two totally different sets of data, one when you're connected, and a different when not.

There's a great video presentation about this that was presented at Google I/O 2010.  See: [Developing Android REST client applications](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html)